# Where to save scripts on DD-WRT power-less-safe?

Tags: script, dd-wrt, cron

i have saved script into `/tmp` folder but when router lost power, file was deleted. Is there any safer variant to save? I need to run this script every minute by cron.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/tmp` is the directory for temporary files.  This is the one place you never want to put anything you want to keep.

`/root` is the home directory and is a reasonable place to put your script.  You may want to put experimental scripts there.

The traditional place for local scripts is `/usr/local/bin` or `/usr/local/sbin`.  These files will be kept over reboots.  There is a full set of directories under `/usr/local` for you to use.

The command `man hier` will display a document about the file system hierarchy.

If you don't have sufficient flash for a read-write file system, you will need to add space from elsewhere.  Depending on the DD-WRT version this can be a USB flash drive (hardware permitting), FTP, SMB, or NFS.  Which, if any, work will depend on the build you are running.

Comment: `/root` does not exists, in `/usr/...` vi throws `Read-only filesystem`. Because insufficient space on routers flash, `man` is not installed by default.

Comment: @Misaz It appears you have very little flash memory,  I've updated my response for options that may be available.  Check the DD-WRT website for details.